# Left join using a condition

Tags: mysql, select, join, left-join

I have this issue.

I need to get this fields from my matching table:

```
date, points
```

Then i have an `epos_id` field as well in my matching table..

I have another `rbpos_epos` table which has `epos_id` and `location` field.

I need to get the `location` from the `rbpos_epos`  using joins.. something like this:

```
SELECT matching.date, matching.points, matching.time,matching.location,matching.epos_id,rbpos_epos.epos_id,rbpos_epos.location
FROM matching  WHERE matching.user_id="'.$id_user.'"
LEFT JOIN rbpos_epos where matching.epos_id=rbpos_epos.epos_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    first_table.date,
    first_table.points,
    first_table.time,
    first_table.location,
    first_table.epos_id,
    rbpos_epos.epos_id,
    rbpos_epos.location
FROM
    first_table
LEFT JOIN
    rbpos_epos ON first_table.epos_id = rbpos_epos.epos_id
WHERE
    first_table.user_id = "'.$id_user.'";
```

Comment: Check `location` field is empty or not.

Comment: Thank you, you were rght, i'm sorry for the confusion :)
i'm accepting this as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use on instead where -

```
    SELECT matching.date, matching.points, matching.time,matching.location,matching.epos_id,rbpos_epos.epos_id,rbpos_epos.location
   FROM matching LEFT JOIN rbpos_epos ON matching.epos_id=rbpos_epos.epos_id      
      WHERE matching.user_id="'.$id_user.'";
```

Comment: What is this ? copy paste ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.date, m.points, m.time,m.location,m.epos_id,re.epos_id,re.location
FROM matching  m 
LEFT JOIN rbpos_epos re ON m.epos_id=re.epos_id
WHERE m.user_id= 10
```

Comment: What is the issue. Add sample table data